# Make function to animate when in view more flexible

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code to animate a couple of numbers when scrolled into view. Everything is working fine. However, currently it only works with ONE set of numbers and tied to ONE div (with an id). I'd like to make it become more flexible, making it work for more than 1 sets of numbers.The DIV ids can be counter1, counter2, counter3 etc.

```
var a = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
var oTop = $('#counter1').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
if (a == 0 && $(window).scrollTop() > oTop) {
$('.counter-value').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    countTo = $this.attr('data-count');
...
```

Here's the pen: 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bQWpjJ

Thanks for you help!

Comment: What do you mean by " making it work for more than 1 sets of numbers." ?

Comment: in the code the numbers are inside <div id="counter1">. I have more set of numbers inside <div id="counter2">, <div id="counter3"> etc. I've also added the second set of numbers to codepen.I wanted to animate all sets of number using the same effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could revise your implementation by first iterating over each counter using `$('#counter1, #counter2').each( .. )`.

Inside of each iteration, you'd effectively re-use your existing code by setting up a `window.scroll()` handler for that counter instance.

You'd also move `var a = 0` inside of the iteration, so that your code tracks the unique scroll offset for this counter instance.

Finally, you'd want to ensure that you select `'.counter-value'` elements for the current `counter` instance of the iteration:

```js
$('#counter1, #counter2').each(function() {
  
  var a = 0;
  var counter = $(this);
  
  $(window).scroll(function() {

    var oTop = counter.offset().top - window.innerHeight;
    
    if (a == 0 && $(window).scrollTop() > oTop) {
    
      $('.counter-value', counter).each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
          countTo = $this.attr('data-count');
        $({
          countNum: $this.text()
        }).animate({
            countNum: countTo
          },

          {

            duration: 2000,
            easing: 'swing',
            step: function() {
              $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
            },
            complete: function() {
              $this.text(this.countNum); 
            }

          });
      });
      
      a = 1;
    }

  });

})
```

```css
.spacing {
  width:100%;
  height: 1280px;
  position:relative;
}
.counter {text-align:center}
.counter-value {display:inline-block; padding:20px 40px; margin:0 20px; border:1px solid #ddd; font-family:Arial; font-size:50px; font-weight:bold}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="spacing"></div>
<div id="counter1">
    <div class="counter-value" data-count="300">0</div>
    <div class="counter-value" data-count="400">100</div>
    <div class="counter-value" data-count="1500">200</div>
</div>
<div class="spacing"></div>

<div id="counter2">
    <div class="counter-value" data-count="500">100</div>
    <div class="counter-value" data-count="600">200</div>
    <div class="counter-value" data-count="1700">300</div>
</div>
<div class="spacing"></div>
```

Here's a [working codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PxmzgZ) - hope that helps!